# Can I assign/construct an std::variant<Ts...> to/from an std::variant<Ts..., Ys...>?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, boost-variant

It seems to me that assigning something that could be apples or oranges to something that could be apples, oranges or strawberries is well-defined.

Why then, can I not do [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23e3873ad3264a5a)?

```
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int> v1{42};
    std::variant<int, char> v2{v1}; // copy construction
    v2 = v1; // copy assignment
    v2 = std::move(v1); // move assignment
    std::variant<int, char> v3{std::move(v2)}; // move construction
}
```

Conceptually, this seems all right. Even [boost::variant allows it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e84eefc2537e5881) (even though std and boost variant aren't exactly the same beast). I couldn't find a defect report or proposal, so I'm probably missing some dark-corner-of-C++ reason why it's not allowed.

Comment: You might still do something like: `auto v1 = std::visit([](auto e) -> std::variant<int, char>  { return e; }, v2);`.

Comment: First, the usual nitpick, you aren't assigning, you are copy initializing. Beyond that, for said constructor to exist it will need to play nice with [c'tor (4) here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant). The specification of which looks daunting enough as it is.

Comment: @Storyteller, right, I first had a copy assignment, then "simplified" the code to this. Both have the same problem though.

Comment: Edited the question to ward off nitpickers ;).

Answer (score 2):

It's just not natively supported in the standard library, for whatever reason. `std::variant` was a very long, very contentious process. Maybe this particular aspect just wasn't high on anyone's list?

The only possible technical concern about adding such a converting constructor and converting assignment operator are weird pathological interactions with the current one. Right now, `variant<Ts...>` has a constructor taking a `T&&` which it tries to pick a `Ts` for. This has potential to clash, and you'd have to answer the question of what you want to happen here:

```
struct X { X(variant<int>); };

variant<int>    v = 42;
variant<int, X> w = v;
```

Currently, this is valid, and `w` holds an `X` constructed from `v`. Would you want this to change and have `w` hold the `int` `42`?

---

For now, you just have to do it manually:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To variant_cast(From&& from) {
    return std::visit(
        [](auto&& elem) { return To(std::forward<Elem>(elem)); },
        std::forward<From>(from));
}
```

You won't get as nice a syntax (and the above implementation isn't SFINAE-friendly), but it gets the job done:

```
using V2 = variant<int, char>;
auto v2 = variant_cast<V2>(v1);
v2 = variant_cast<V2>(v1);
v2 = variant_cast<V2>(std::move(v1));

// at least this one is stil easy :-)
auto v3 = std::move(v2);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know if there is something in the standard that disallows this as it is allowed with `boost::variant`.

Comment: @P.W Well, yes, the standard literally disallows it. There are no such constructors/assignment operators.

Comment: I guess you have to write `return To(std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem));` in the lambda. `Elem` is not defined anywhere.